# How can I change Spring locale cookie name?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cookies, localization

The cookie for spring MVC locale is named by default as `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.LOCALE`.

How can I set this name to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie name can be set in the configuration of the `localeResolver`, used to store locale changes in session cookies:

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></property>
    <property name="cookieName" value="YOUR_LOCALE_COOKIE_NAME"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks to [dimitrisli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185723/dimitrisli) for the link to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-cookie).

Answer (score 4):

The Java config way:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    final CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("YOUR_LOCALE_COOKIE_NAME");
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
}
```

Comment: How to do this in spring boot 3? localeResolver bean already exist. Can answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75555800/overide-localeresolver-bean-in-spring-boot-3

Answer (score 2):

Using Java config:

```
@Bean
public HandlerInterceptor localChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeInterceptor;
}
```

Using XML config:

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:interceptors>
```

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-cookie)

Comment: This sets the name of the parameter used in request to change localization, not the cookie name. ([LocaleChangeInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html))