# Overide localeResolver bean in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Before migrate to spring boot 3 I created `localeResolver` bean like this:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(MessageSourceProperties properties) {
    CookieLocaleResolver clr = new CookieLocaleResolver(properties.getCookieName());
    clr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return clr;
}
```

But right now this bean already defined and i get error:

```
The bean 'localeResolver', defined in class path resource [com/app/autoconfigure/internationalization/I18nAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

This bean is created in class `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

How to override it?

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue too while trying to create a bean inside a configuration imported from library using `@AutoConfiguration`.
The `LocaleResolver` bean was being created in `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` which has `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)`, the configuration I was providing should have had higher precedence, so adding `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 9)` to my configuration class solved the issue.

Keep in mind that this is only valid when your application is without the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation

Answer (score -2):

There are two approaches to solve this problem :

1. Change the method name 'localeResolver' to a different one; since "Spring takes the names of the annotated methods as bean names."
2. Set the name property of the @Bean annotation.

For reference you may follow :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-definition-override-exception

Comment: Changed name is not decision. For correct i18n working necessary localeResolver bean name

Comment: localeResolver bean uses for determining which locale is currently in use. Right now this bean already exist. I fixed my problem by removing @EnableWebMvc anotation (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24209), but this is not the best decision.